# Getting extra lines, but I don't know why

Tags: c#, wpf, output

I am making a WPF program, and right now I want to be able to open and merge files. I have a button to open a file and I have a button to merge the file, and when I don't implement the "onTextChanged" method both buttons work properly and the files are formatted properly. But if I implement the onTextChanged method and use the merge file button, the previous 'file' gets extra lines in its output.

Open Button Code:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Open windows explorer to find file
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.CheckFileExists = true;
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() ?? false)
        {
            //clears the buffer to open new file
            buffer.Clear();
            //string to hold line from file
            string text;
            // Read the file and add it line by line to buffer.
            System.IO.StreamReader file =
              new System.IO.StreamReader(ofd.FileName);
            while ((text = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                buffer.Add(text);
            }
            //close the open file
            file.Close();

            //write each element of buffer as a line in a temporary file
            File.WriteAllLines("temp", buffer);
            //open that temporary file
            myEdit.Load("temp");
        }
    }
```

Merge Button Code:

```
private void merge_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.CheckFileExists = true;
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() ?? false)
        {
            string text;
            // Read the file and display it line by line.
            System.IO.StreamReader file =
              new System.IO.StreamReader(ofd.FileName);


            while ((text = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                buffer.Add(text); // myEdit.AppendText(text);
            }

            file.Close();



            File.WriteAllLines("temp", buffer);
            myEdit.Load("temp");
        }
    }
```

And when I execute this code, it adds lines in between the last 'file's output:

```
private void myEdit_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tCheck.Stop();
        tCheck.Start();
    }
private void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        tCheck.Stop();


        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            buffer.Clear();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            //  pulls text from textbox
            string bigS = myEdit.Text;

            // getText();

            for (int i = 0; i < (bigS.Length - 1); i++)
            {
                if (bigS[i] != '\r' && bigS[i + 1] != '\n')
                {
                    sb.Append(bigS[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    buffer.Add(sb.ToString());
                    sb.Clear();
                }

            }
        }));


    }
```

If you are wondering why I don't use the Split method of a string, it is because I need to open 50+ MB text files and I get an out of memory exception upon using it. I really just want to keep formatting the same when I merge a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow this is a one line fix.

Original Line of Code:

```
buffer.Add(sb.ToString());
```

Changed (Correct) Line of Code:

```
buffer.Add(sb.ToString().Trim());
```

The changed worked, however if someone has any idea where these extra lines are coming from that would be helpful.